# React-router onEnter doesn't trigger

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm setting up routes for a React app. When entering my Homepage, I'd like to log some data from Auth0. To do so, I'm simply user the onEnter attribute, but it seems like it doesn't work.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Route, IndexRedirect} from 'react-router'
import AuthService from 'utils/AuthService'
import Container from './Container'
import Home from './Home/Home'
import Login from './Login/Login'

[...]

const requireAuth = (nextState, replace) => {
  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace({ pathname: '/login' })
  }
}

const parseAuthHash = (nextState, replace) => {
  console.log('LOG SOMETHING YOU IDIOT');
  if (/access_token|id_token|error/.test(nextState.location.hash)) {
    auth.parseHash(nextState.location.hash)
  }
}

export const makeMainRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Route path="/" component={Container} auth={auth}>
      <IndexRedirect to="/home" />
      <Route path="home" component={Home} onEnter={requireAuth} />
      <Route path="login" component={Login} onEnter={parseAuthHash} />
    </Route>
  )
}

export default makeMainRoutes
```

For some reason, when I'm on /login, nothing appears in console. I tried with alert too, doesn't trigger. Did I miss something ?

Comment: plus one for the logging message

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using v4, which has done away with onEnter: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route

Instead, you are to use the render prop. Their new docs have an example of this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Here's the main idea of it:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      React.createElement(component, props)
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```